# Long time configuring SSIS package from SQL Server

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I keep configuration for SSIS package in my SQL Server db. There are 6 connections to different db's in my package. All of them configure from SQL Server.
Before starting package attempt to configure all them twice, it is known specific of SSIS package. But each of them is configuring about 20-30 seconds. In sum it is about 5 min.
What can be a root cause of that? I understand that the problem maybe on db side, where i store my configurations, but maybe you have some another ideas.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what is the value of the maxconcurrentexecutables property do you have. By default it is -1. if you set to 1 then there will be only one thread working or you can control the thread of the processor. Set to either -1 or put 6 for your package. may be this will help.